# Functions R Programming

Tags: r, function

I have information about revenue in cumulative form for the whole year, I would like to get monthly revenue. Lets say first month revenue is 3.2M, and second month revenue is 2.2M, but my second entry is sum of first two months.

Revenue
3.2
5.4
7.6
9.2
I would like to extract revenue as below
ExRevenue
3.2
2.2
2.2
1.6

How can I extract the revenue using R functions. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
df <- read.table(header=T,text="Revenue
3.2
5.4
7.6
9.2")
df$ExRevenue <- c(df$Revenue[1], diff(df$Revenue))
df
#   Revenue ExRevenue
# 1     3.2       3.2
# 2     5.4       2.2
# 3     7.6       2.2
# 4     9.2       1.6
```